# Run a iOS App on version 4.3 on Mountain Lion

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios4, simulator

I'm using XCode's latest version on Mountain Lion and would like to test my Apps for iOS 4.3.

How can I adjust the simulator or install previous versions of XCode to test for iOS 4.3 in stead of testing for 5.1 only?

Within my XCode preference -> Downloads I'm not able to see the 4.3 simulator

[image]

EDIT:

I manually copied the folder of the iPhone 4.3 SDK from an old iMac which had an old XCode running to my working computer. Turned out that this fix only worked for device testing and not for testing in the simulator. So I needed to have an old device with iOS 4.3 installed, this eventually worked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install Simulator SDK 4.3 to Xcode 4.4 on Mountain Lion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651773/how-to-install-simulator-sdk-4-3-to-xcode-4-4-on-mountain-lion)

Comment: Check my answer <br> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353099/run-app-using-xcode-4-6-in-ios-4-3-simulator/16353379#16353379

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the 4.3 simulator.

Go to "Preferences" in Xcode and then the "Downloads" tab and you *may* see this:

[image]

I made this screenshot on my 10.7 machine but looking at the (supposedly) identical Xcode install on 10.8, I only see the 5.0 simulator as an installable option.  It may be that you have to install the 5.0 simulator before the 4.3 one appears, or 4.3 is only supported on Lion.

Comment: Think I will look for an other machine to test on which is running Lion then?

Comment: I'd recommend trying to install the 5.0 simulator first and see if the "4.3 simulator" appears as an option at that point.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed [this identical and duplicate question to yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651773/how-to-install-simulator-sdk-4-3-to-xcode-4-4-on-mountain-lion?rq=1).