# How do I install the iOS 4.3 Simulator on Xcode 4.5?

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, ios-simulator

I have Xcode 4.5 installed via the App Store, and it has iOS 5.1 and 6.0 support, but not iOS 4.3. Nor is it available for download in the "Downloads" tab of Preferences. I tried grabbing it from another computer and putting it on this one, as [described by Dominik Porada](http://pieces.dominikporada.com/post/31915100911/simulator), but alas that did not work. Maybe there are other files I need? How do I get the iOS 4.3 SDK back?

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651773/how-to-install-simulator-sdk-4-3-to-xcode-4-4-on-mountain-lion/11743817 iOS 4.3 Simulator disappeared in Xcode 4.4 for Mountain Lion but not for Lion but the above question should be fairly relevant.

Comment: Ah-ha! Thanks @BoA. Guess I just need to hang onto a copy of Lion for a while.

Comment: A VM for Lion might be a good option.

Comment: Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353099/run-app-using-xcode-4-6-in-ios-4-3-simulator/16353379#16353379

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I actually did get 4.3 to appear in the Xcode 4.3 menu just by copying the `iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk` file to the `Xcode.app` package, as [described by Dominik Porada](http://pieces.dominikporada.com/post/31915100911/simulator). I think I just had to restart Xcode again, and there it was!

But it doesn't work. As pointed out in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651773/how-to-install-simulator-sdk-4-3-to-xcode-4-4-on-mountain-lion/11743817), iOS 4.3 is not supported on Mountain Lion. Might work fine for Lion, though.

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution to run iOS 5.1 in XCode 4.2. Try following the same procedure. Try copying it from a previous version of XCode.Haven't tried it out myself.But see if it works.

To get Xcode 4.2 on Snow Leopard to run code on a device running iOS 5.1 you can do this:

If you have another Mac running Lion and Xcode 4.3.1 you can copy the files from:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.1 (9B176)
```

Place the copied files in the equivalent place on your Snow Leopard Mac: probably

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
```

Similarly copy the iOS 5.1 SDK files found in this directory:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk
```

Also copy 'version.plist' from the Lion machine in the iPhoneOS.platform folder to the Snow Leopard machine.

Re-start Xcode on the Snow Leopard machine and re-connect the devices and it seems happy enough.

If you don't have access to a machine with Lion and Xcode 4.3.1:

You can get the files out of the 4.3.1 DMG which can be downloaded from Apple here: Downloads for Apple Developers.

Mount the DMG, Show Package Contents on the Xcode icon and drill down to

```
/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
```

Follow the steps above.

You might find it more convenient to use Apple's proprietary ditto method (sudo ditto src dest) in the terminal window to copy the folders.

Comment: Looks like for later versions of Xcode, all you have to do is copy the `iPhoneSimulator$version.sdk` to the `Xcode.app` package. See my answer for more on that.