# How can i update iPhone from iOS 4.2 to 4.3 to test with it?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad, xcode4.5

I would like to know how can i update my device from iOS 4.2 to 4.3 to test with it using XCode 4.5 because that version of XCode doesn't allow to test in 4.3? if it's not possible, is there any solution to test on iOS 4.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I regret to say that you cannot upgrade your device to an older firmware version like iOS 4.3 for which Apple is not providing signed shsh blobs anymore. Your only chance is to use the simulator.

For future projects, you might think of using a tool like TinyUmbrella to extract the shsh blobs for your device/iOS as long as apple is providing them (right now only for iOS6). You will then store them safely for future use.

Once Apple has ceased to sign a given iOS version, installing that version is conceptually the same as downgrading, so you might find interesting [this article](http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=16496).

Comment: How can i use iOS 4.3 in XCode 4.5?

Comment: Try with this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560399/how-do-i-install-the-ios-4-3-simulator-on-xcode-4-5

Answer (score 0):

if your iphone is jailbreaked and has backed up your ssh of iOS4.3, it will be possible.

Comment: 1.use TinyUmbrella and start it's server

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to 4.3 is going to be an issue. But if you manage to get your hands on a device on iOS 4.3 you can test on that device by creating an Ad Hoc distribution build and syncing it to the phone through iTunes or iPhone Configuration Utility. Just make sure the Deployment Target for the build is set to 4.3 or lower.