# How to install iOS 4.3 Simulator on xCode 5?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, deployment-target

How to install iOS 4.3 Simulator on xCode 5? It's required to test the application on Deployment Target 4.3.

Comment: There are a couple of similar questions (about Mountain Lion, about xCode 4.5, etc) that seem to come to the conclusion that you cannot. The 4.3 simulator is no longer available. You can still set the deployment target, but you have to test on real devices (or a newer simulator).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install the iOS 4.3 Simulator on Xcode 4.5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560399/how-do-i-install-the-ios-4-3-simulator-on-xcode-4-5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, there's no official way to add the iOS 4.3 simulator. You *may* be able to hack it somehow but I don't know how and I wouldn't recommend it.

Secondly, if you really want to support iOS 4.3 you need an actual device to test it on. The Simulator is not 100% accurate and it certainly doesn't mirror the performance of a real device. If it existed, using the Simulator would be a good "first pass" but it's not a substitute for the real thing.