# Trying to Test an iPad with iOS 4.3 in Xcode 4.5

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4, osx-mountain-lion, ios4

So, I'm trying to test a game of ours on the Xcode simulator. I'm using OSX-Mountain Lion and have Xcode 4.5, but I need to test iOS 4.3 with the iPad simulator. Is this possible?

Comment: What if the answers are incorrect?

Comment: How are these answers incorrect ? If *you think* they are, leave a comment, update your question. The other question I was talking about was answered, you commented *"**Nice 1! Thank you** – user1752552"* on an answer. You should accept that one too.

Answer (score 1):

Set the **deployment target as 4.3** in build settings

Comment: Click on your project then go to the summary tab and you should see the Deployment Target drop down to select your target. This is a shortcut for the Build Setting

Comment: Good thought - in theory, this "should" work, but I am not able to reproduce the behavior I am looking for without the iOS 4.3 iPad simulator. All this does is change the minimum OS that the project is built for.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your deployement target is set to iOS 4.3, and download the **iOS 4.3 Simulator** (in Xcode : *Settings* -> *Downloads* -> *Components* -> *iOS 4.3 Simulator*). When it's done, select "iPad 4.3 Simulator" in your scheme (top left selector on Xcode's main window), and run !

Comment: iOS 4.3 is not supported on Mountain Lion. See this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11743817/1752552)